# Angular $scope variable not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angular, I define a scope variable `$scope.letter_content`. When the view is loaded, I load string from my database and set it to `$scope.letter_content`. Then, I populate on a texteditor(Froala) i'm using.

Below is the code for the view:

```
    {{letter_content}}
    <div ng-if="formData['page_number'] == 1 ">
        {{letter_content}}
        <textarea id="froala-sample-2" froala="froalaOptions" ng-model="letter_content"></textarea>
    </div>
```

So basically I set `letter_content` as ng-model for the texteditor. So when I make changes on the texteditor, it modifies the value `$scope.letter_content`.

One thing I found it weird is that when I modify the text in the texteditor, it changes `{{letter_content}}` inside the div. However, it does not update `{{letter_content}}` outside the div.

When I'm done editing the text in my texteditor, I send send a put request to update the value in the database with `$scope.letter_content`. However, it ends up sending `{{letter_content}}` outside the div which ends up not updating the content.

Why is this weird thing happening?

Comment: Let's do a small experiment - change `ng-if` to `ng-show`, if it worked I'll write a detailed answer

Comment: @AranS Yes it is `ng-show` . Thanks for pointing that out mate. Cheers!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Actually this has been discussed in more links.

Don't use primitive type variable. Instead of that use object in scope.

For example,
Don't use like `$scope.primitiveVariale` instead of this `$scope.object={primitiveVariale:null}`

So in view use like `object.primitiveVariale` then this will be reflect in all the view. Please see the following links.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Answer (score 27):

I had very similar but even weirder problem where I was updating one of my `scope` variables using the response from an HTTP call, surprisingly, my view will not update unless I make another HTTP call and by another I mean any other random HTTP call.

Using the `$apply` worked for me,

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
     $scope.resultData.totalResults = response.data.total;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this was useful and $apply worked for me for similar situation.

Comment: `.$applyAsync` should even prevent `Error: [$rootScope:inprog]`

Comment: Its working but there is issue that it doesn't change the value in the form if the are changed and post for saved request, they remain the same as they are in check boxes when they were applied... I don't whats that issue.

Comment: Can someone explain why this works? It worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

The `ng-if` directive create a new scope, so the `letter_content` inside the `div` is in the `ng-if` scope, but the `letter_content` outside is in the controller scope.

Read the API doc to know which directive create new scope.

To avoid this kind of problem consider using the [controllerAs syntax](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/)

Comment: "The ng-if directive create a new scope". Thank you! I change to ng-show and it started work.

Answer (score 6):

Do not use plain values like this, you need to put such values into an object, so try in your controller:

```
$scope.obj = { letter_content: null};
```

and then in your view:

```
{{obj.letter_content}}
```

Answer (score 3):

can you ever heard of angular's `dot notation`?

## solution

put `letter_content` in an object. `froalaDetails.letter_content` for example. then update that value and everything should work exactly like you want.

## explanation

watch this very short video to get the full details: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot

Comment: this video is accessible on a paid plan - is there any other reference for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

```
 $scope.object = {letter_content:null};

  {{object .letter_content}}
    <div ng-if="formData['page_number'] == 1 ">
        {{letter_content}}
        <textarea id="froala-sample-2" froala="froalaOptions" ng-model="object .letter_content"></textarea>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was scratching my head for 3 days and finally could able to resolve the issue by `$rootScope`, I have used `$rootScope` and the value is automatically updating the view (HTML template).

Controller:

```
$rootScope.myVariable = 'update label'
```

Now if you update the value of `myVariable` via any click/change events the updated value will be updated in the HTML template.

HTML file:

```
<h3>{{myVariable}}</h3>
```